# How Can I Communicate With Blender as Server/Client?

Tags: python

I Need To Send Data To Blender From My Local Python App [Same Machine],
I've tried the Socket Lib, but it Freezes Blinder
so, how can I do that!

Edit:

This is The Script that I need to Send from Python And Receive it in Blender To Make Animation

[image]

#edit 2:
This is The Script of Client in Blender

[image]

This is The Script of Server

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could I use BGE, Python, and sockets to make a multiplayer game?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98780/could-i-use-bge-python-and-sockets-to-make-a-multiplayer-game)

Comment: Can you share the blender script you are using?  A lot of people do manage to successfully use sockets to get data into Blender, but it's difficult to say what's not working if I don't know what you're trying.

Comment: Perhaps [This gist](https://gist.github.com/MatteoRagni/91e0216c84d39aa0575fc25001759051) might be helpful?  The problem is that it polls, and the devs on devtalk recommend using async io

Comment: @MartyFouts I've Added The Script of Blender that I need to send from my python code to Blender To Make Animation Automatic, I've used basic socket script code to send and receive but it Freeze the blender bcoz it stuck in while loop.

Comment: I think I might have asked for the wrong thing, because that script doesn't have any socket code in it.  Can you show me the code that you're trying to use to read from the socket?

Comment: @MartyFouts I've added it

Comment: Blender is probably freezing because you're executing the while loop on the main thread.  As soon as it finishes reading the data it tries to receive again and that hangs waiting for more data that never comes.  Does the other side close the socket connection when it's done sending?

Comment: No, I need to be able to send data when I need not once,

Comment: @MartyFouts if there is any other efficient method can u mention it please

Comment: While I'm trying to work something out, take a look at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46505/can-a-blender-script-stay-in-memory-and-listen-to-a-socket  I think you can adapt it

Comment: https://github.com/hku-ect/Python-MOCAP-tools/blob/master/blender/addons/modules/pythonosc/osc_server.py does exactly what you want, but it's complex and I think overkill for your application.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thank you

Comment: @PeterBoshra some additional info you might be interested in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283898/python-server-and-client-in-blender/283914#283914