# Passing commands to blender with GUI open

Tags: python, command-line

is there a way to pass python commands to blender with the GUI visible? I have a simulator made in Matlab where measurements can be changed. When one of these measurements change I want the script to pass a command to an open blender GUI so the changes are made in real-time. I have everything working except that if I use the interactive python console I can't see the GUI, it's just grey. Right now I have to use the command to run blender and then run a script, but to make any changes I have to rerun blender with an updated script.

Answer (score 0):

It could be any way that you can pass data from one Python script to another. I am not going to pretend I know a lot about that, but one simple and primitive way could be to save a script to a file and check if the file is changed from Blender. You can make an add-on(See Blender's Text Editor Templates menu) with a [timer](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html), that checks for scripts to run.

I believe there are more sophisticated ways as well. For example see [Python: Server and Client in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283898/python-server-and-client-in-blender). But that looks considerably more difficult to make.